# How to verify if the string also starts and ends with a space in shell script?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

How to verify if the string also starts and ends with one or more space(s) ?

```
if [[ $username =~ [^0-9A-Za-z]+ ]]
```

(basically input should be alphanumeric, no spaces anywhere, even in the beginning or in the end, and no commas, underscores, hiphens etc)

The above regex unfortunately does NOT match leading & trailing spaces, but it matches spaces in between ?

Without awk, sed, is there any way I can fix the above regex to match leading & trailing spaces also ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Glenn `if [[ $username =~ [^0-9A-Za-z]+ ]]` This was my original regex, and I want the user to only enter alphanumerics (all others should not be accepted including spaces, underscores etc). I am using a read inside an infinite while loop and terminating only on valid input.

The regex matches all non alphanumerics and even strings with space in between as expected but it was not matching entries with leading and trailing spaces (I thought so).

Then I have realized that its not the regex but the "read" command which was automatically trimming the leading and trailing spaces, so by the time it comes to regex, variable itself was trimmed.

**"The trick around this, is to redefine your IFS (Internal Field Separator) variable. By default, IFS is set to the space, tab and newline characters to delimit words for the read command."** got this from this blog

http://fahdshariff.blogspot.in/2008/06/read-file-without-trimming-leading.html, and I have fixed my script accordingly.

Thanks for following up and explaining the details !!

Answer (score 5):

Bash regexes can be tricky with quoting: regex metachars must NOT be quoted, but, since whitespace is significant in the shell, spaces must be quoted. This regex matching a string beginning and ending with a space:

```
[[ $s =~ ^" ".*" "$ ]] && echo y
```

To test if a string contains a space, do one of:

```
[[ $s =~ [[:space:]] ]] && echo y
[[ $s == *" "* ]] && echo y
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, the regex should match leading and trailing spaces too.

Comment: "      abc"   or "abc         " should also be matched.

Comment: `if ! [[ $username =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ ]]` matches all non alphanumeric inputs except for leading & trailing spaces of input strings. example "abc  " or "   abc"

Comment: @Sandeep, actually, that matches anything but a single alphanumeric character (due to your use of anchors). "AB" with no spaces will be matched. Can you make it clear to us exactly what you do and do not want to be a valid input?

Comment: Could not put entire text here, so added as answer, please see that @glenn

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if [[ $username =~ "^ [^0-9A-Za-z]+ $" ]]
```

Comment: Not sure it's because of quotes, the regex is not matching other characters which it did earlier, like comma, spaces in between etc

Comment: Also, I think that would match only one space (begin & end) not any number right ?

Answer (score 1):

> (basically input should be alphanumeric, no spaces anywhere, even in the beginning or in the end, and no commas, underscores, hiphens etc)

Uh, unless I'm missing something...

```
if ! [[ $username =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ ]]
```

Comment: This is matching one or more spaces, but if I give "  abc" or "abc   " it misses these, but you kind of hit that !! Thanks, I have got clue now, that negation is the key :)

Comment: It matches leading and trailing spaces, but if that space is followed/preceded by characters, it misses them.

Comment: What is the significance of "!" here, why are strings like "  abc" and "abc   " not matched ?

Comment: `!` negates the return code of the command for purposes of `||`, `&&`, and `if`. " abc" and "abc " aren't matched because they contain a "[space] anywhere".

Comment: The regex matches "abc   def", so it maches spaces in between. It misses if spaces is at the beginning or at the end, not if space is present anyplace !! This is kind of wierd.

Comment: Not here it doesn't... `$ username="abc def"`
`$ [[ $username =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ ]] ; echo $?`
`1`

Comment: Are you sure with that "abc   def", it works fine for me, infact that was working even with my original regex.

Comment: `$ read username`
`abc def`
`$ [[ $username =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ ]] ; echo $?`
`1`

Comment: Tried again, spaces in between are matched with your and even my regex